# How to enable iAd in (Safari) App Extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I can add iAd banner to normal apps or the hosting app of the extension (banner shows "You're connected to iAd"). However, iAd seems not working in App Extension. It shows a blank banner once the App Extension is launched.

`canDisplayBannerAds` of the extension's viewcontroller has been set to true. Neither `bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:` nor `bannerViewActionDidFinish:`, nor `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` are triggered.

Comment: By the way, Apple said: ["The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016."](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a).

Comment: iAd "App Network" is not all iAd. Normal iAd banner is still available. http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/15/apple-will-discontinue-iad-app-network-for-developers-on-june-30th/